QEMU, Debian VM doesn't boot after shutdown on M1
On M1, I 'm trying to run a Debian 12 VM.
After the installation process, whether configured using a deb_preseed.cfg (within the Automated Install) or through the GUI configuration, it fails to run (cannot find the boot) only when the QEMU engine is quitted (powered off).
The boot installation:
qemu-system-aarch64 -m 2048 -M virt -cpu host -monitor stdio \
    -accel hvf \
    -device virtio-gpu-pci -device usb-ehci -device usb-kbd \
    -drive if=none,file=debian.qcow2,cache=writethrough,id=hd0 \
    -device virtio-blk-device,drive=hd0 \
    -device virtio-net,netdev=net0 -netdev user,id=net0,hostfwd=tcp::2222-:22 \
    -bios qemu-efi-aarch64_debian/QEMU_EFI.fd \
    -cdrom debian-12.5.0-arm64-DVD-1.iso

In order to run the VM, I m just remove the option -cdrom as on Ubuntu case.
I 've also try a lot of variants of -drive if=none,file=debian.qcow2,cache=writethrough,id=hd0, even without usage of virtio-blk-device, however it still remains.
Furthermore, when I 'm trying to import on qemu-system-aarch64 the options below, it repeats the installation process again and again.
    -kernel vmlinuz \
    -initrd initrd.gz \
    -append "auto=true priority=critical preseed/url=http://10.0.2.2:8080/deb_preseed.cfg"

Note: I should mention that as long as the DebianVM remains powered on, I still have access to the VM even after a VM's reboot sudo reboot. However, only when the machine is powered off, the UEFI cannot find the boot and repeatedly attempts to
Start the PXE/HTTP over IPv4/v6.

There isn't a Debian's Boot option, in UEFI-Boot Manager
The same configuration on Ubuntu runs properly.
I 've already tried different than ubuntu's UEFI, the QEMU_EFI.fd
I m using the vmlinuz and initrd.gz from ftp.debian.org

